# Sidekiq super_fetch - how is the rescued job executed?

Tags: ruby-on-rails-5, sidekiq

I have a rails app with `sidekiq-pro` version `5.2.1` So recently we introduced `super_fetch` in our code. It does rescue the jobs when the Sidekiq shuts down, now when these rescued jobs are executed again, does it restart from the beginning of the worker or it starts from where it was interrupted?

Answer (score 1):

Sidekiq calls `perform` each time. There’s no magic to restart at some arbitrary line of Ruby.